# Rendering images starting from the last image

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a series of images (named: `example001.jpg` to `example100.jpg`) and I want to output a video for these images starting from the last picture and back to the first one (i.e., in descending order).
I use the folloing command:

> ffmpeg -r 10 -i example%03d.png -start_number 100 output.mp4

But, the output video is not showing the desired video.
What is wrong in the used command?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [reverse filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html):

```
ffmpeg -framerate 10 -i example%03d.png -vf reverse -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

- Option placement matters. `-start_number 100` is an input option for the [image file demuxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) but you were trying to use it as an output option. However, it won't start at 100 and count backwards.
- Alternatively, you could use another tool to pipe the images in the desired order.
- `-pix_fmt yuv420p` was added to ensure playback in crappy players.